# Phoenix Valley or Phoenix valley?

Tags: capitalization

So, I'm working on a document that is going to go out to the public shortly and I'm hung up on this one item.

> The company is excited about recent growth trends in the Phoenix **V**alley.

I'm just not sure if the 'v' should be capitalized or not.

Comment: did you try googling it? All results come with wiht a V.

Comment: I did. But all the results are proper nouns. Phoenix Valley Metro (Organization), Phoenix Valley Magazine, etc. However, I did just find an East Valley, which is capitalized. I'll go with the uppercase 'V'

Comment: Why would you use the definite article "the" before Phoenix Valley?

Comment: It depends on whether "Phoenix Valley" has attained status as a named geographic feature.  Some valleys have, some not.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the name then it should be capitalised. If you are describing the geography it would be lower case e.g  walking in a wooded valley, as apposed to visiting the Phoenix Valley.